# Bluemix Docker Container cf ic login the local Docker daemon is not reachable to authenticate

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am running through the directions to work with docker containers and Bluemix using the ic plugin.  When I run the command:

`cf ic login`

I receive the message:

> Your system was authenticated with the IBM Containers API, however the
>   local Docker daemon is not reachable to authenticate it with the IBM
>   Containers registry. You can still run IBM Containers on the cloud but
>   will not be able to push or pull images.

If I work with docker locally without running the cf ic login, all seems to be fine.

Following the cf ic login, if I run any docker commands such as:

`docker tag ibmjstart/bluemix-wordpress registry.ng.bluemix.net/myNamespace/wordpress`

the commands fail with the message:

> Error response from daemon:  405 Method Not Allowed
>
> ## Method Not Allowed
>
> The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Any guidance on things to check is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer that V.Bontempi provided was extremely helpful and it may just have been me not quite grasping what he was stating, but to clarify it was actually setting the env variables to point **exclusively to Bluemix** which was causing the issue.  When you set the env variables

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/jeff/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

This tells docker to work exclusively with Bluemix versus the local instance.  So, if I set the env variables, after doing this when I attempted to work with a local image and tag it as per the tutorial found here:

[WordPress on Bluemix Containers](http://blog.ibmjstart.net/2015/05/22/wordpress-on-bluemix-containers/)

and I tried running the command:

```
docker tag ibmjstart/bluemix-wordpress registry.ng.bluemix.net/[namespace]/wordpress
```

using my namespace, the command would fail with a 405 error.  On the other hand, if I run the following sequence of commands **without the export**, everything works as expected:

```
cf login
cf ic login [-a https://api.ng.bluemix.net] [-H https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/containers] [-R registry.ng.bluemix.net]
docker tag ibmjstart/bluemix-wordpress registry.ng.bluemix.net/myNamespace/wordpress
docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/[namespace]/wordpress
```

The support team provided me with the following explanation:

1) Install and configure docker to work locally 
    This is the first think you need to do, so you can create your images locally before pushing to IBM Containers in Bluemix.
    For this step to work you have to configure docker environment variables. To do this you can run the following command:
           eval "$(docker-machine env default)"

This will set the environment variables for you local docker. Docker will not work if you not set this variables.
   After setting this you can try basic docker commands, like:

```
      docker images
      docker ps
```

You will notice that these commands would not work if you have not set the environment variables.

2) Log in to Bluemix and IBM Containers
    Now that docker is installed and configured you can log in with the following commands:

```
       cf login 
       cf ic login 

After that you can start playing with your images and pushing them to IBM Containers in Bluemix once they are ready.
```

Thanks to the Bluemix support team for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this is because cf ic output is suggesting you that you have to switch docker from your local engine to Bluemix one before using docker client to work remotely.
As suggested from the output of cf ic login, you simply have to set the following env vars to remote Bluemix references, exactly as suggested
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
DOCKER_HOST
DOCKER_CERT_PATH

Then if you wish to switch back simply set value to their previous values (eventually print them and save before switching)

Comment: Hi V,  Thanks for your suggestions.  As per the output of the cf ic login, I did export the DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY DOCKER_HOST DOCKER_CERT_PATH values that were provided.  I also checked that these variables were set by running the env | grep -i docker command.  I should have mentioned that when I posted my question.  So, there must be some other step I need to take or issue that needs to be resolved.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you check that you was successfully logged in on cf, you have selected the right org and space and you are using the right registry? If you wish you could provide all the steps you are following to do that, starting from "cf api"

Comment: V, Thanks!     I  run cf login and pick my dev space along with my default org without any errors.

I then run:

cf ic login [-a https://api.ng.bluemix.net] [-H https://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/containers] [-R registry.ng.bluemix.net]

Comment: I then see: Where I receive the message:

Client certificates are being retrieved from IBM Containers...
Client certificates are being stored in /Users/jeff/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net...
OK
Client certificates were retrieved.

Checking local Docker configuration...
Your system was authenticated with the IBM Containers API,
however the local Docker daemon is not reachable to authenticate it
with the IBM Containers registry. You can still run IBM Containers
on the cloud but will not be able to push or pull images.

Comment: If I run docker in a new docker window, docker commands run without any issues.  If I run docker in a window where I export Docker_TLS_VERIFY, etc, I will receive the 405 errors.