# Bluemix: local Docker daemon is not reachable to authenticate it

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am having almost the same problem, as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590476/bluemix-docker-container-cf-ic-login-the-local-docker-daemon-is-not-reachable-to). Unfortunately, the provided answer in this thread does not solve my issue.

cf login works fine

cf ic login fails:

```
$ sudo cf ic login
Password:
Client certificates are being retrieved from IBM Containers...
Client certificates are being stored in /Users/XX/.ice/certs/...
Client certificates are being stored in /Users/XX/.ice/certs/containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net/bd67571...
OK
Client certificates were retrieved.

Deleting old configuration file...
Checking local Docker configuration...

Your system was authenticated with the IBM Containers API,
however the local Docker daemon is not reachable to authenticate it
with the IBM Containers registry. You can still run IBM Containers
on the cloud but will not be able to push or pull images.

You can choose from two ways to use the Docker CLI with IBM Containers:


Option 1: This option allows you to use "cf ic" for managing containers on 
IBM Containers while still using the Docker CLI directly to manage your 
local Docker host.
Use this Cloud Foundry IBM Containers plug-in without affecting the local Docker environment:

Example Usage:
cf ic ps
cf ic images



Option 2: Use the Docker CLI directly. In this shell, override the local Docker environment to connect to IBM Containers by setting these variables. Copy and paste the following commands:
Note: Only Docker commands followed by (Docker) are supported with this option. 

export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net:8443
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/XX/.ice/certs/containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net/bd675...
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

I tried the suggestion in the mentioned thread and ran eval "$(docker-machine env default)". 
As a result, the command 'docker images' and 'docker ps were executing fine.

Then, if I run

```
cf login 
cf ic login
```

I get the error above when executing cf ic login. I also tried Option 2 as the error message suggested, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: What OS are you using? and what is the version of your docker (docker -v)?

Comment: Mac OSX 10.11.2, just updated cf and docker. So: Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5 and cf version 6.15.0+fa1bfe2-2016-01-13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able recreate the error you are seeing when I run `cf login` and `cf ic login` with sudo in Mac. If I run without `sudo` then `cf ic login` works fine.

Run all commands **without** `sudo`:

```
$ cf login 

$ cf ic login 
Client certificates are being retrieved from IBM Containers...
Client certificates are being stored in /Users/adasilva/.ice/certs/...
Client certificates are being stored in /Users/adasilva/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/ef4c3396-1d7a-4843-8d05-fd255b6899d2...
OK
Client certificates were retrieved.

Deleting old configuration file...
Checking local Docker configuration...
OK

Authenticating with registry at host name registry.ng.bluemix.net
OK
Your container was authenticated with the IBM Containers registry.
Your private Bluemix repository is URL: registry.ng.bluemix.net/adasilva

You can choose from two ways to use the Docker CLI with IBM Containers:

Option 1: This option allows you to use "cf ic" for managing containers on IBM Containers while still using the Docker CLI directly to manage your local Docker host.
    Use this Cloud Foundry IBM Containers plug-in without affecting the local Docker environment:

    Example Usage:
    cf ic ps
    cf ic images

Option 2: Use the Docker CLI directly. In this shell, override the local Docker environment to connect to IBM Containers by setting these variables. Copy and paste the following commands:
    Note: Only Docker commands followed by (Docker) are supported with this option. 

    export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://containers-api.ng.bluemix.net:8443
    export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/adasilva/.ice/certs/containers-api.ng.bluemix.net/ef4c3396-1d7a-4843-8d05-fd255b6899d2
    export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

    Example Usage:
    docker ps
    docker images
```

Comment: Finally, that helped me solve the problem. I had to change the owner of everything in the .ice folder. It was all owned by root, that's why I thought I'd need sudo. Don't know how this happened. Thanks